# all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk' in Django

Tags: python, django, rest

I've got a problem with Django and the Django REST Framework.

When I go to http://mynameislee.co.uk/albums/ it works fine and returns the Django Framework fine but when I try http://mynameislee.co.uk/albums/1 I get all() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'.

This is my code.

**urls.py**

```
# API
url(r'^albums/$', 'canary.views.album_list', name='album_list'),
url(r'^albums/(?P<pk>[0-9])$', 'canary.views.album_detail', name='album_detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def album_list(request):

# List all tasks, or create a new task.

if request.method == 'GET':
    album = Album.objects.all()
    serializer = AlbumSerializer(album, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

elif request.method == 'POST':
    serializer = AlbumSerializer(data=request.DATA)
if serializer.is_valid():
   serializer.save()
   return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
else:
  return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@login_required
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def album_detail(request, pk):

# Get, update or delete a specific album

try:
  album = Album.objects.all(pk=id)
except Album.DoesNotExist:
  return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

if request.method == 'GET':
  serializer = AlbumSerializer(album)
  return Response(serializer.data)

elif request.method == 'PUT':
  serializer = AlbumSerializer(album, data=request.DATA)
  if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
  return Response(serializer.data)
else:
  return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

elif request.method == 'DELETE':
  album.delete()
  return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**models.py**

```
class Album(models.Model):

  album_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  album_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
       return self.album_name
```

Comment: The proper REST convention would be to have /album/1, not /albums/1. Note that DRF does everything that your code does automatically, if you use the built-in views or viewsets/routers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant use `all` with a filter set.

```
album = Album.objects.all(pk=id) #wrong
```

Use `filter` instead:

```
album = Album.objects.filter(pk=id)
>>> type(album) -> 'QuerySet'
```

Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) with a lot of examples.

And as @Bjorn suggested: you can also use `get` that will save you getting the item from the queryset:

```
album = Album.objects.get(pk=id)
>>> type(album) -> 'Album'
```

Comment: If `id` is a single item, you can also use `Album.objects.get(pk=id)`.

Comment: Boomcubist is passing `pk` to `album_detail`, not `id`

Comment: Thanks @RickyA. Changing it to .filter gave me a QuerySet; Object has no attribute but changing it to .get fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
album = Album.objects.filter(pk=id)
```

instead of

```
album = Album.objects.all(pk=id)
```